# Garbage collector: .NET 4.6 vs .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, .net-core

I've found some interesting thing, but could not find out why is it working so.

I've made two apps in *Visual Studio 2017*:

1. *Console App (.NET Framework)* - .NET 4.6
2. *Console App (.NET Core)* - .NET Core 1.1

Then I've written some code:

```
class TestApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objectsList = new List<Entity>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            objectsList.Add(new Entity());
            if (i % 1000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class Entity
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
        public int Number1 { get; set; }
        public int Number2 { get; set; }
        public long LongNumber1 { get; set; }
        public long LongNumber2 { get; set; }
        public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

        public Entity()
        {
            Text1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Text2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Date1 = DateTime.MaxValue;
            Date2 = DateTime.MinValue;
            Number1 = int.MaxValue;
            Number2 = int.MinValue;
            LongNumber1 = long.MaxValue;
            LongNumber2 = long.MinValue;
            Numbers = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                Numbers.Add(int.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I've ran this code in two apps and saw that *.NET Core* runs it without any problems, while *.NET Framework* throws an exception of type **System.OutOfMemoryException**.

**QUESTION:** It looks like *.NET Core* garbage collector works better, right? But why is it so? Can somebody explain it to me or give some sources where I can find some explanation?

**P.S.** My PC has about 3GB free RAM when I run the apps.

Comment: And you are sure you have the same settings for each build - i.e. both have Platform Target set to x86?

Comment: I have set Platform to Any CPU on each project.

Comment: And what about the "Prefer 32-bit" setting?

Comment: It was checked on .NET Framework app. I have unchecked it and now two apps work the same. Problem solved! 
That's not good, cause I need to find some differences in .NET Framework and .NET Core memory management. So I thought that I've found one.